# Is this a good use case to use a service?

Tags: android, android-service

I have an application that listens to broadcasts and sends broadcasts.
When the application sends a broadcast it expects a broadcast back from another application.

I catch the broadcast in my receiver and then send the content to a regular java class called 'decode'.
Here I check the contents of the broadcast and call a method on the mainActivity to launch another activity.

This mainActivity has no real UI, so I was thinking of making a service to replace it.
  So I instead of calling mainActivity from decode, I would make a service and call a method from that service.

Now , since I have no experience with android services, is this a good case to use a service ?
Where can I find a good example of android services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, this is the time to use a `Service` since you should never call an `Activity` method from outside the `Activity`. I will give you the most basic `Service` as a template, and then you can add stuff to it as you like:

```
public class MyService extends Service{

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override 
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i("daim", "MyService has started ...");
        startMyMethod();    
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("daim", "MyService has stopped ...");    
    }

    public void startMyMethod(){
        // do your work
    }
}
```

Now in order to start this service, you call the method `startService` and to stop it, call the method `stopService`. Now if you want to stop the service inside the service, for example when your work is done. You could call `stopSelf();` inside your service method. Google for `startService` and `stopService` in order to see what parameters are needed, and how to call them depending if you are inside an `Activity` or not, this is where you might need the `Context` if you call it from inside a class.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html